# Are there any programming languages with "unusual" access modifiers?

Tags: programming-languages, access-modifiers

Counting the "usual" ones as

- Accessible to all
- Accessible to the same package, assembly, etc.
- Accessible to the same package or derived classes.
- Accessible to derived classes.
- Accessible to self only.

Are there any programming languages (where the concept applies) which have any access modifiers other than these?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net CLI has all the access modifiers you mention: all (`Public`), same assembly (`Assembly`), same assembly or derived classes (`FamilyORAssembly`), derived classes (`Family`), self only (`Private`).

But it also has "same assembly *and* derived classes" (`FamilyANDAssembly`). Many CLI languages (including C#) do not let you use this modifier, but some do (like C++/CLI, where this modifier is called `private protected`).